# Long time SSH key to github stops working, and now github tests welcome me as org_name/other_project

Tags: ssh, git, github, ssh-keys

A ssh key that had once worked with Github stopped working and nothing I did would fix it. All Git requests would die with the standard `git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

In github, I am a part of an organization and there are several repos there.
I visually checked or tested my...

- SSH and GPG keys under my GitHub account
- There was nothing nefarious added in my `~/.ssh/config` file
- made sure that `eval $(ssh-agent)` was run and that
- my key was included `ssh-add ~/.ssh/for_github`
- `ssh -T git@github.com` it said it successfully connected!
- 

What gives? Curious though, why does it say `welcome org_name/other_project`?

```
    user$ ssh -T git@github.com
    Hi org_name/other_project! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Answer (score 0):

All the forums said that the output for `ssh -T git@github.com` would be `welcome <username>`, Why was mine giving me the name of a repo, especially since I was not even working in that repo, and not my own username?

```
    user$ ssh -T git@github.com
    Hi org_name/other_project! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

In my poking around, I realized that there were different places to store SSH keys - SSH keys on the user and Deploy keys on the repo. I looked back carefully in both of these and realized that I had entered my long-working SSH key as a deployment key as well. In ignorance, I had somehow doubled these up. There was no warning that I remember.

A quick delete of the duplicated deploy key and I was back in business. My `git push` would work again and the ssh github test now had my username.

```
    user$ ssh -T git@github.com
    Hi my_username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

**TL:DR   ---   Do not use same ssh key for user authentication and project deployment**